Unable to read "wr_en, fifo_in" data using module instantiation
Is there anything wrong with my instantiation?
8 to 32 bit converter is working fine.
Input to fifo is read only when wr_en is high.
wr_en is connected to output signal of valid_q (when valid_q=1, conversion of 8 to 32 bit is done)
The below instantiation is connecting "wr_en" to "valid_q" in module fifo @ line 12 of my source code
"fifo_in" is connected to "data_out" of converter
fifo reads 32 bit data only when wr_en=1
do we need to drive wr_en_tb and fifo_in_tb in test_bench again?
Already "valid_q" and "data_out" are generated using module converter_8_32
@ line12 of source code
converter_8_32 fifo_dut(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.valid_q(wr_en),.data_out(fifo_in));
// fifo to read 32 bit data if wr_en=1
module fifo(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input wr_en,
    input [31:0] fifo_in,
    output [31:0] fifo_out);
 
reg [31:0] reg_fifo;
 
//fifo instantiation with converter module
converter_8_32 fifo_dut(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.valid_q(wr_en),.data_out(fifo_in));
 
always @(*) begin
    if(!rst) begin
        reg_fifo<=0; end
        else if (wr_en==1'b1) begin
            reg_fifo<=fifo_in; end
        else reg_fifo<=0;    
end
assign fifo_out=reg_fifo;
endmodule
 
//converter block to convert 8 bit input to 32 bit output for every 4 clocks.
////output is valid if valid_q=1 where we receive 32 bit data out
 
module converter_8_32(
    input clk,
    input valid,
    input rst,
    output reg valid_q,
    input [7:0] data_in, //8 bit input
    output reg [31:0] data_out); //32 bit data out
 
reg [7:0] temp_reg [0:3];
 
integer N=4;
always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (!rst) begin     
        data_out<=0;
        valid_q<=0;
            end
 
    else if (!valid) begin
            data_out<=0;
            valid_q<=0;
            N<=4;
                       end
               
    else begin            
        temp_reg[N-1]<=data_in;
        N=N-1;    
        if (N==0) 
        begin 
            valid_q<=1;
            N<=4;
            end
                else begin
                valid_q<=0;
                data_out<=data_in; end
            end
        end
                                            
 
always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (N==0)
        // concatentaion operator to concatenate previous 3 data along
    // with preset data_in to generate 32 bit data
        data_out<={temp_reg[3],temp_reg[2],temp_reg[1],data_in};
            
end
 
endmodule


// **TEST BENCH**
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module fifo_tb();
reg clk_tb;
reg rst_tb;
reg valid_tb;
reg [7:0] data_in_tb;
wire valid_q_tb;
wire [31:0] data_out_tb;
 
reg wr_en_tb;
reg [31:0] fifo_in_tb;
wire [31:0] fifo_out_tb;
 
converter_8_32 dut_converter (.clk(clk_tb),.rst(rst_tb),.valid(valid_tb),.data_in(data_in_tb),.valid_q(valid_q_tb),.data_out(data_out_tb));
fifo dut_top (.clk(clk_tb),.rst(rst_tb),.wr_en(wr_en_tb),.fifo_in(fifo_in_tb),.fifo_out(fifo_out_tb));
 
always # 1 clk_tb=~clk_tb;
always #8 valid_tb=~valid_tb;
integer i;
 
initial begin
 clk_tb=0;
 rst_tb=0;
 valid_tb=1;
 data_in_tb=0;
 #2.5 rst_tb=1'b1; 
 //valid_tb=1'b1;
 #0.5;
 for (i=0;i<255;i=i+1) begin
     data_in_tb=i;
     #2;
 end
end
endmodule


The instance of converter_8_32 inside the fifo module is missing some connections.
When I run a simulation, I see these compiler warnings using the Cadence simulator:
converter_8_32 fifo_dut(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.valid_q(wr_en),.data_out(fifo_in));
                      |
xmelab: *W,CUVWSI : 2 input ports were not connected:
xmelab: valid
xmelab: data_in

I see similar warnings when I run on another simulator as well (Synopsys).
Check your simulation log files for similar messages.  If your simulator does not show warnings, try your code on the EDA playground site.
